# Yii2 export after filter gridview

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii2

This is my url after I done my filtering.

`http://localhost/VMS/frontend/web/index.php?r=report%2Ffilter&ic_passport=&name=&unit_no=&category=4&purpose=`

1) I tried to get the param inside the url

`$category = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('category');`

`Yii::$app->request->getParam('category');`

`Yii::$app->request->get('category');`

but it does not works. Anything I done wrong?

2)Let say I wanted to do query based on the URL so that I can only export out the result that only been filter

```
  `Table1::find()
  ->andwhere(['category_id'=>$category])
  ->andWhere(['visitor_name'=>$visitor_name])
  ->andWhere(['ic'=>$ic_passport])
  ->andWhere(['unit_no'=>$unit_no])
  ->andWhere(['purpose_id'=>$purpose])
  ->all(),`
```

Based on the filter url, it will come out result that have category 4. But when I used my own created query, it will come out 0 result because other attribute is blank. Why in the url the attribute can be leave blank and it works but in the query it cant?

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**

```
  `Table1::find()
  ->andFilterwhere(['category_id'=>$category])
  ->andFilterWhere(['visitor_name'=>$visitor_name])
  ->andFilterWhere(['ic'=>$ic_passport])
  ->andFilterWhere(['unit_no'=>$unit_no])
  ->andFilterWhere(['purpose_id'=>$purpose])
  ->all()`
```

Just use `->andFilterWhere`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `get()` and `getQueryParam()` should definitely work (first one is basically alias for the second) - if it's not working you must do something wrong.

2) Use `andFilterWhere()` instead of `andWhere()` - it works the same way but if variable in condition is empty it's ignored.